# Postgresql: EXPLAIN query with COPY give error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I wanted to see why my copy queries are taking long time, so I tried to use Explain with COPY as shown below.

```
EXPLAIN 
COPY
"Table1"
TO STDOUT;
```

However, I get this `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "COPY"
LINE 2: COPY`

If I use the COPY without EXPLAIN it works as expected but I simply can't get it to work with EXPLAIN. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `copy` is not "explainable". But as it simply runs `select * From table1` you can do `explain select * from table1`

Comment: Besides, there isn't a lot to explain about `COPY`. There is only one way to execute it.